# using the emoji in an if statement to see if the emoji the user reacted with is a specified one doesn't work

Tags: discord.py

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  print("works")
  if payload.emoji == "":
    print("also works")
```

in my code, the "print(works)" statement prints, but not the "print(also works)" doesn't print.
The strange thing is, when I print the emoji, its the same one the if statement is using. so I don't know what's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :   str(payload.emoji) == ""